# UIActivityViewController's "More" button breaks orientation settings

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` supports only portrait mode. But when I present a `UIActivityViewController`, the orientation behavior is strange.

When the `UIActivityViewController` is presented, I can rotate the device to any orientation without the share sheet being rotated. This is correct.
But when the share sheet is presenting, and I put the device horizontally, then click the "More" button, the "More" settings page will be horizontal. Then when I finish the settings and back to share sheet, the share sheet along with my presenting `UIViewController` becomes horizontal. This breaks my layout.

I have tried the trick that enclose the `UIActivityViewController` in a `UINavigationController`, but that does not change the behavior after clicking "more" button.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should make another uinavigationcontroller and present uiactivityviewcontroller from there. In this code _image is a UIImage yo wan to share. BlankViewController is just place holder viewcontroller you can create in IB you can also make it's view's background colour to clear and do what ever appearance changes you want to do.

```
 __weak  CurrentViewController  *weakSelf    =   self  ;

 UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[_image] applicationActivities:nil]   ;
 UIViewController        *viewC  =   [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlankViewController" bundle:nil] ;
 UINavigationController  *navC   =   [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewC]  ;
 activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
{
[weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion: ^ {
    ;    // Your completion handler
}]  ;
};[self presentViewController:navC animated:NO completion: ^ {
[navC presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion: ^ {
    ;
}]  ;
}];
```

Comment: Hi, I have read this trick and tried before I asked. This didn't fix orientation after clicking "more"..

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIActivityViewController and override supportedInterfaceOrientations to allow only Portrait.